# Symantec network intrusion protection slowing backups to a crawl

Tags: windows-server-2008, symantec-endpoint-protection

We recently went to a disk-based appliance solution for our company's backups.

I've set everything up and monitoring the backups shows that they are crawling.  Like 64 MB/min on a 1 GB ethernet network.

We're also running Symantec Endpoint Protection on all servers and clients.

I've found that if I disable network intrusion prevention on a server, the speed of the backup jumps to 1GB/min.  That is very significant.

Question is, what does network intrusion prevention do for servers?  From what I can tell it's there to block malware from websites and since no one really browses the web from these servers can I just disable it for servers?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you turn Network Intrusion Prevention off on all of your systems.

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH104434

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO80870

Comment: I was thinking about turning it off for servers and leaving it on for clients.  Would that work?

Comment: Personally I would turn it off on all systems and make sure the Windows Firewall is turned on. That in combination with the real time Symantec AV engine should provide sufficient protection. I haven't seen any Symantec installation where Network Intrusion Prevention is enabled that hasn't had the same issue you're having.